# Is there an option to change view of pagerAdapter in onTouchListener?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created a PagerAdapter class which implements View.OnTouchListener. In this class I have an ImageView that is setOnTouchListener to the implemented listener. Problem is that I tried to change **the size or image of that ImageView but it won't change** when touched. However the **click is triggered** and if I add something other than view change it will run it. The class where this is used only uses this, all changes are made here.

There are no errors popping in console nor warnings in code.

(apart from the clickAccessibility which shouldn't be responsible - I've tested it with performClicks in code and it behaved the same)

And so is there an option to change view of pagerAdapter in onTouchListener? ..if not is there a different way to do the thing I am trying to make here differently?
(please provide an example)

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements View.OnTouchListener{

private ImageView infoIcon;

@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

   layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_recipe_layout, container, false);

   infoIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.mainInfoIconButton);
   infoIcon.setOnTouchListener(this);

   container.addView(view);

   return view;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.mainInfoIconButton) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,44,view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                        (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,44,view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
             infoIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
             infoIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_info);

             return true;
         } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {      
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,48,view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()),
                        (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,48,view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
             infoIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
             infoIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_info);

             Log.i("MTAG", "Click Triggered"); //this gets printed in console

             return true;
         }
       return false;
    }

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put `ImageView infoIcon;` outside the method.

```
public class SliderAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements View.OnTouchListener {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;

    public SliderAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.nutrition_recipe_layout, container, false);

        ImageView infoIcon = view.findViewById(R.id. mainInfoIconButton);
        infoIcon.setOnTouchListener(this);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.mainInfoIconButton) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

                params.width = dp2px(context, 120);
                params.height = dp2px(context, 120);
                view.setLayoutParams(params);

                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                params.width = dp2px(context, 100);
                params.height = dp2px(context, 100);
                view.setLayoutParams(params);

                LogUtil.i("MTAG", "Click Triggered"); //this gets printed in console

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private int dp2px(Context context, int value) {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, value, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

}
```

Comment: apologies that was a typo, in the code I tried to put a layout and the imageView on top of it.. and tried to change the layout's size but it didn't work as well